# Deleting branches of legacy code

Tags: version-control, clearcase

One of the products which I have been working started some 10 years back. There were several developers who had worked for this project and several merges had happened throughout the life time of this project. Now taking the version information (clear case version tree), applying labels, checking out are taking long time. Is it a good idea to delete old branches and (say like 3 years back) to improve the maintainability of the code and performance of the version control? We're using clear-case as version control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ClearCase with UCM, then deleting a branch (which is only possible if you delete every versions on that branch for every file) isn't a good idea.
And with base ClearCase, it is still tricky and quite complex to properly remove everything.

Start first by **obsoleting** those branches and see if that speeds up operations like `mkelem` or `lsvtree`.

See [`cleartool lock -obs`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm).

Comment: Note: locks prevents rmelem or rmbranch (https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251621), but since I am not too enthusiastic about removing anything in a ClearCase, that doesn't matter.